# numpy array , TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.int64 object

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm going to find the max value of each column and its index in a `2D numpy ndarray` but I got the error

`TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.int64 object`

here is my code

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,0,4,5,8,12,8],
              [1,3,0,4,9,1,0],
              [1,5,8,5,9,7,13],
              [1,6,2,2,9,5,0],
              [3,5,5,5,9,4,13],
              [1,5,4,5,9,4,13],
              [4,5,4,4,9,7,4]
             ])
x,y = np.argmax(a) 
#x should be max of each column and y the index of it
```

does anybody know about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:

```
x = a.max(0)
y = a.argmax(0)
```

Answer (score 3):

`np.argmax` as you have it is flattening the array and returning a scalar, hence your unpacking error.

Try:

```
ncols = a.shape[1]
idx = np.argmax(a, axis=0)
vals = a[idx, np.arange(ncols)]
```

Output:

```
>>> idx
array([6, 3, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2])

>>> vals
array([ 4,  6,  8,  5,  9, 12, 13])
```